# How do I configure a single Windows Server 2012 as Remote Desktop Services installation

Tags: domain-controller, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2012

we (a small 5 employee company) ordered a hosted server to use it as a use-from-everywhere database frontend. Our database basically is a SQL Server 2008 with an MS Access frontend, which I intend to install on the server, so every employee can login from everywhere via RDP.

So far so good.

The configuration wizard now gives me the option to configure the server as a) "Role based or feature based installation" or b) "Remote Desktop Services installation"

Since I thought it'd be best to make full use of the new virtualisation features of Server 2012 and use b) I chose this, but the wizard asks me to add the server to the Domain first, which of course does not exist, since this is only a single server setup. I also can't create a domain, because I would need to chose a) in the first place.

Since I am completely new to Windows Server 2012 and not really an admin (I am more like a IT generalist) I am kinda stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is install [***VDI***](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/virtualization/vdi.aspx). VDI required an AD domain with the Server 2008 schema extensions and in Server 2008 functional level even back at the time of its introduction in Server 2008. The requirement to have an Active Directory still stands with Server 2012.

You *can* install the Remote Desktop Session Host role without having an AD domain, though - simply use the *"Role-based or feature-based installation"* and tick the required roles instead.

Also, since you presumably have a Windows Server 2012 Standard license, you are entitled to running two virtualized instances of Windows Server without purchasing a further license. So you might choose to set up an additional VM running your AD DC, effectively enabling you to use VDI at the cost of 2 GB of RAM and 50 GB of storage (even less with de-duplication enabled) on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I need RDP CALs or VDA CALs with the solution you suggested?

Comment: @MAD9 obviously you will, but details are [***outside of SF's scope***](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405) - talk to your vendor or MS representative about that.